# How can I set a color of a table header based on a value from MySQL?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysqli

I have an HTML table which contains a TH that has rowspan = 3

[image]

[image]

When I submit the form, I want to change the color of the TH to "green" and INSERT a "submitted = 1" to MySQL

When I refresh the page, the default values are set and it goes back to black

I want to read from MySQL and set the Green color based on those "submitted" fields.

I have a php file that is selecting from the DB and I can retrieve the "Submitted" and "EventName", but I do not know how to tie them in to an EXISTING table.

My PHP code looks like this

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $options= '';
    // output data of each row
   echo ("in");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";

            echo "<th style='color: rgb(0, 128, 0);'>".$row['eventName']."</th>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo $options;
```

How do I tie this in to a Table that exists and merge them together?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see the SQL Query. Do you want the Text color to be green or the cells background color?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT eventName FROM swimMeetData WHERE submitted =1";

I want just the color to be "green" just like the screen shot above

The results show correctly in the UI, but I cannot figure out how to change the actual table in my HTML code

Comment: I don't understand what is not working? What is the condition that would change the color of the text? What other table are you referring to?

Comment: just to bring some clarity. in the SQL statement above you say "submitted =1" but then in the question it says "isSubmitted" based on the fact that you likely copied the SQL statement can you update the question if the property should be named "submmited". just for consistency

Comment: I would generate all HTML elements from Javascript, just to avoid unnecessary server charge. You can pass any data you need via AJAX from the PHP.

Comment: I like that.
I get a list of the Events from the DB and use AJAX to return the data.
I am looping through the list of events and trying to compare them to what is being returned 
I just am having issues matching the returned data and the table data ???

Comment: Please edit your post and include the JS/JQuery and HTML you are using.

Comment: You could try to append the new row to the existing table in your ajax success function using jquery: $('table').append(data); . But I would just rebuild the entire table in your ajax call and then replace it.

Comment: I have made progress but have hit the following issue:

Ajax data returns  - "200 Yard Medley Relay 100 Yard Free Style" .. etc
I am trying to compare the innerText from the Table headers to the data, but it keeps returning -1

 success: function (data) {
        var res = $('#meetTable tr th#eventNames');
          var test ="200 Yard Medley Relay 100 Yard Free Style"
               for (var i=0;i < res.length; i++){
                   if (res[i].innerText.indexOf(test) >=0)
                   {
                    alert ("in")
                   }
               }

It is always -1

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want something like this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $options= '';
        // output data of each row
       echo ("in");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            $color = "color: black;";
            if($row['IsSubmitted']){
             $color = "color: green;";
            }
                echo "<th style='".$color."'>".$row['eventName']."</th>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    echo $options;
```

Comment: Thanks Tommy
The SQL data is only created when I submit a row, for example the screen shot in the question
There are 12 different events in the Table with rowspan 3 (as shown above)
See updated screen shot

I want to be able to scan the DB and only update the data (events) in the DB to green

Comment: Tommy, How can I set the CSS/Style on an array element?

    'success: function (data) {
    var res = $('#meetTable tr th#eventNames'); 
    for (var i=0;i < res.length; i++){
    if (data.indexOf(res[i].innerText) >=0)
 {
    res[i].css("color","blue")
    }
    }'
I cant do it this way..

Comment: @user5451365 cool, you could update your question with final answer if you want, for the next people who may check this question

Answer (score 1):

just place an if statement inside of the while block and have a variable default to black and if submitted == 1 then set the variable to green

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        $backgroundColor = "black";
        if($row['submitted'] == 1)
        {
            $backgroundColor = "green";
        }


            echo "<th style='color:".$backgroundColor.";'>".$row['eventName']."</th>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your SQL Query, `WHERE submitted = 1`, would mean you only get `eventName`, but do not get `submitted` in the record set.

If you change it to something like:

`SELECT eventName, submitted FROM swimMeetData GROUP BY eventName, submitted;`

You can use a conditional statement based on `$row['submitted']`. That could look like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<table>\r\n";
    echo "<tr>\r\n";
    echo "<th style='color: " . ($row['submitted']?"rgb(0, 128, 0)":"rgb(0, 0, 0)") . ";'>{$row['eventName']}</th>\r\n";
    echo "</tr>\r\n";
    echo "</table>\r\n";
}
```

Comment: OP is a little unclear about the problem that they are having. Although based on the SQL query provided in the comments I believe this is correct and the best solution. +1

Comment: The results are returned great. My question is how to merge them into a table that is already existing. (Please see new screeshot image in question)

I am now using AJAX, but it is overwriting the whole table with the returned TH

Comment: If that is the case, we need to see your JS/JQuery code that is collecting the data and creating the table. We would also need to see the HTML of your existing table.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it using an AJAX call

```
 success: function (data) {
               var res = $('#meetTable tr th#eventNames');

               for (var i=0;i < res.length; i++){
                   if (data.indexOf(res[i].innerText) >=0)
                   {
                       res[i].style.color = 'green'
                   }

               }
```

This will loop through my list of "Events" and check them with my backend MYSQL. If the event is in the DB, it finds it and sets the text color to Green.